# Неправильная генерация сертификата X.509

Tags: java, linux, centos

В проекте используется ЭП для подписания некоторых данных на форме. При тестировании локально на своем ПК (Windows) все происходит идеально: юзер загружает свой файл-сертификат, из данных генерируется сертификат и заносится в бд. Генерация происходит за счёт библиотеки `java.security.cert`; Но как только я закидываю варник на сервер разработки (Centos 6) и начинаю дебажить, то во время генерации поле `Key` заполняется неправильно, а именно -`EC public key`, не так как на локальном пк. Может ли быть такое, что на сервере разработки что-то нужно донастроить? Потому что мне кажется дело именно в линухе :(

Comment: ДВС? (а вот это просто символы, т.к. букв в слове ДВС не достаточно для комментария)

Comment: @AntonSorokin , Доброго времени суток :)

Comment: что можно сказать однозначно: программа linux к описанному не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения. составьте, пожалуйста, [mcve] и внесите в текст вопроса, нажав [edit] (это и для вас полезно, потому что при составлении примера с большой вероятностью вы и обнаружите причину некорректного поведения вашей программы).

Comment: А попробуйте переписать вопрос без фамильярностей, жаргона и смайликов, добавив побольше логов и версий - Java/CentOS. Вопрос врядли касается *nix т.к. все происходит в jvm сверяйте библиотеки